# what does the `run() {}` do in javascript/Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I see in Aurelia site, one of the article uses `run() {}`. What does this method in general do? it is a lifecycle hook or it is a new Javascript 2016 method?

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

```js
import {Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
    config.map([
      { route: ['welcome'],    name: 'welcome',       moduleId: 'welcome',      nav: true, title:'Welcome' },
      { route: 'flickr',       name: 'flickr',        moduleId: 'flickr',       nav: true, auth: true },
      { route: 'child-router', name: 'childRouter',   moduleId: 'child-router', nav: true, title:'Child Router' },
      { route: '', redirect: 'welcome' }
    ]);
  }
}

class AuthorizeStep {
  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
      var isLoggedIn = /* insert magic here */false;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return next.cancel(new Redirect('login'));
      }
    }

    return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: [It's a lifecycle method](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/latest/class/LoadRouteStep) written using ES2015 method syntax. Search the site you linked to and you'll see various services using a `run` method. It isn't a new thing in ES2015.

Comment: There it is! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple pipeline steps to your router config. Each of the pipelines must implement `PipelineStep` interface:

```
interface PipelineStep {
  /**
   * Execute the pipeline step. The step should invoke next(), next.complete(),
   * next.cancel(), or next.reject() to allow the pipeline to continue.
   *
   * @param instruction The navigation instruction.
   * @param next The next step in the pipeline.
   */
  run(instruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): void;
}
```

([source code](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/765686e11716964ab279bc4f9d6cb70891909ce7/src/pipeline.js#L48))

As you can see there must be `run` method. At some point later `run` methods from all the steps will be executed.

So the answer to your question: no, it's not something ES2015 introduces, but rather a convention pipeline steps must follow.